# How to create a React NativeSelect with Checkbox in Material-UI for multi-option selection?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, dropdown

I'm looking to replace my existing dropdown menu with checkboxes in a React application using Material-UI. Currently, I have a dropdown that allows multiple selections with checkboxes, and I'd like to switch to using the NativeSelect component from Material-UI while retaining this checkbox functionality. The goal is to enable users to select and manage multiple options easily. You can find the current code in my question title for reference.

```
<FormControl>
                                <InputLabel required >Work Unit</InputLabel>
                                <Select
                                    id="work-unit-mutiple-checkbox"
                                    multiple
                                    value={props.values.workUnit}
                                    input={<Input />}
                                    renderValue={(selected) => {
                                        if (selected.length == 1 && selected[0] == '-1') {
                                            return TextConst.WORK_UNITS_PLACEHOLDER;
                                        }
                                        let showText = [];
                                        props.workUnitList && props.workUnitList.responseObject && !props.workUnitList.responseObject.message && props.workUnitList.responseObject.map(e => {
                                            if (selected.includes(e._id)) {
                                                showText.push(e.displayName)
                                            }
                                        })
                                        return showText.join(', ');
                                      }}
                                >
                                    {props.workUnitList && props.workUnitList.responseObject && !props.workUnitList.responseObject.message && props.workUnitList.responseObject.map((e) => (
                                        <MenuItem key={e._id} value={e._id}>
                                            <Checkbox color="primary" checked={props.values.workUnit.indexOf(e._id) > -1} />
                                            <ListItemText primary={e.displayName} />
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    ))}
                                </Select>
                                {workUnitsReq ? <FormHelperText>Work unit is required</FormHelperText> : null}
                            </FormControl>
```

I've tried to replace the existing Select component with the NativeSelect component from Material-UI and adapt the code accordingly. I expected the new NativeSelect to behave similarly to the original Select with checkboxes, allowing users to select multiple options and display them in the dropdown. However, I'm encountering challenges in achieving this behavior, and the selected options are not displaying as expected.

```
<FormControl>
      <InputLabel required>Work Unit</InputLabel>
      <NativeSelect
        id="work-unit-mutiple-checkbox"
        multiple
        value={props.values.workUnit}
        onChange={handleWorkUnitChange}
        renderValue={(selected) => {
          if (selected.length === 1 && selected[0] === '-1') {
            return 'Placeholder Text'; // Replace with your desired placeholder text.
          }
          const showText = props.workUnitList
            .filter((e) => selected.includes(e._id))
            .map((e) => e.displayName);
          return showText.join(', ');
        }}
      >
        <option value="-1">Placeholder Text</option> {/* Replace with your desired placeholder text. */}
        {props.workUnitList.map((e) => (
          <option key={e._id} value={e._id}>
            <Checkbox color="primary" checked={props.values.workUnit.includes(e._id)} />
            <ListItemText primary={e.displayName} />
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
      {props.workUnitsReq ? <FormHelperText>Work unit is required</FormHelperText> : null}
    </FormControl>
```